# Why the grammar is not (LL1)?

Tags: compilers, parsers

Why the grammar is not (LL1)? (e is the epsilon)

$$S \to a A \mid b B \mid a C c $$
$$A \to a A \mid a a A \mid e $$
$$B \to c C \mid D \mid e $$

CHOICE 1: The grammar is Left-Recursive (LR)
CHOICE 2: The grammar is Non-Deterministic (ND)
CHOICE 3: The grammar has FIRST-FOLLOW conflict(s)
CHOICE 4: Both 1 and 3
CHOICE 5: Both 2 and 3
CHOICE 6: All 1, 2, and 3

I found that Correct answer is - CHOICE 4: Both 1 and 3

That means the is Left-Recursive (LR) & has FIRST-FOLLOW conflict(s)

**But I can't understand how it is Left-Recursive (LR)? I thought that it is Non-Deterministic (ND)**

Comment: You seem to be missing part of the grammar. What are the rules for $C$ and $D$?

Comment: there has no rules for C and D . Variables are S, A & B